# Upgraded to 3.3, My Widgets Disappeared

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I upgraded to 3.3 an my widgets went  bye-bye.  Here's the code I'm using... anybody else having this problem?

This code worked perfectly fine for me before the upgrade.

```
<!-- Enable Widgets -->
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
        || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if your theme is compatible with WP 3.3. To check, you may try switching to the default theme (twentyeleven) for a moment by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes. The idea is to force WordPress to fall back to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific issue.

-also, make sure all your plugins are uptodate and compatible with the 3.3. deactivating ALL plugins temporarily to narrow down the problem. If the problem goes away, activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin.

-Ipstenu has put togather an extensive [3.3 troubleshooting guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list). Please review it as well.